# Rose Tree in Haskell -- Finding the Leaves

Tags: haskell, tree

Please consider the following definition of a rose tree in Haskell

```
data Rose a = a :> [Rose a]
        deriving (Eq, Show)

root (a :> rs) = a

children (a :> rs) = rs
```

together with the implementation of the functions to get the root and the children of a rose tree.
The bit where I am still struggling is how to implement the functions

```
size :: Rose a -> Int
leaves :: Rose a -> Int
```

that count the number of nodes in a rose tree, respectively the number
of leaves (nodes without any children).
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3):

```
size (_ :> ts) = ? + sum ?

leaves (_ :> []) = ?
leaves (_ :> ts) = sum ?
```

You will need to use recursion to fill in the blanks, and a common higher-order function.

Comment: I got this from your answer: 
    size :: Rose a -> Int
    size (_ :> bs) = 1 + sum [size v | v <- bs] 

    leaves :: Rose a -> Int
    leaves (_ :> []) = 0
    leaves (_ :> bs) = sum [1 + leaves v | v <- bs]

would this be correct?

Comment: @ramonabacherli, your `size` function looks right, but your `leaves` function looks quite wrong in both cases.